# How do you automatically highlight all objects with same name in Javascript, when you highlight only one in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, visual-studio

In C#, when I highlight a variable name, it is also highlighted everywhere else on the same page where that variable is used in Visual Studio.

When I do the same in JavaScript, this does not happen.

How do make this happen in JavaScript?

Comment: Are you using Visual Studio?

Comment: It is a Visual Studio feature.

Comment: @csanonymus - Yes I am using visual studio

Comment: @Soner Gönül - How do I switch this on?

Comment: Well it works for me..Just make sure you have a .js file and not .htm/.html/.php etc

Comment: I checked the Visual Studio 2012 Tools->Options and there is no such an option for Javascript. And I couldn't find any 3rd party extension as well.

Comment: This is an extension for 2010 http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/0696ad60-1c68-4b2a-9646-4b5f4f8f2e06

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [Highlight All Occurrences of selected word](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/4b92b6ad-f563-4705-8f7b-7f85ba3cc6bb) extension. On double-clicking a word, all occurrences of that word will be highlighted.

Comment: Isn't there a feature like this already inside Visual Studio?

Comment: Yes. Like a charm! :)

Comment: @GIVE-ME-CHICKEN Not for javascript/jQuery

Comment: Thanks, will install and check to see if it works and mark it as the answer.